# Compare two table ids and create third column based on same ids

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have two sql tables, one with id and name and other with id. I want to get as result - table with 3 columns, first id, second name, third true/false if id is in both tables or not. for example :

```
Table 1       Table 2   result ->   Table 3
1   Mike      2                     1 Mike false 
2   John      4                     2 John true
3   Roger                           3 Roger false
4   Richard                         4 Richard true
```

this is what I wan`t to accomplish. Do you have any suggestions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Left join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187518%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) will return row even if a match is not found. This row will consist of null values.

```
select t1.id, 
       t1.name,
       case when t2.id is null 
            then 'False' 
            else 'True' 
        end DoesExist
  from Table1 t1
  left join Table2 t2
    on t1.ID = t2.ID
```